# HTTP receiver does not bind and not listen on the TCP port

Tags: tibco-business-works

I installed Tibco ActiveMatrix BW 6.4 and I wanted to test implementation of simple process with HTTP receiver. In this purpose I created main process with HTTP receiver activity which has been connected with HTTP response sender. Of course, for the HTTP receiver in the properties editor I configured HTTP connector with standard settings. I finally started my process but it turned out that he did not work because HTTP receiver hasn't been binded with the TCP port 8080

```
netstat -p tcp -n | findstr 8080
```

did not return it. 
In the console wasn't any errors or warnings. Additionaly I did same test with process on the MS Windows 10 x64 and Linux Ubuntu x64 systems but the result was the same. Please help me because I haven't got any idea.

BR
Robert

Answer (score 0):

You said that HTTP connector is configured with the correct host and port.
The only reason why it does not work that I see, is that the process must be declared as a component (Module Descriptors>Components)

Comment: @Robert, any news about this case?